# PHP basic security for Web apps Project Structure

Tags: php, .htaccess, slim

I have a web application that has the following structure:

[image: Project Structure]

Here, inside app directory are accessible files for registered users..who can access files under their respective folders upon successful authentication.

Customers, agents and admin will be directed to their respective directories that is accessible to them.

bower_components and globals contains css, js and images files.

I don't want users to access my directory structure.

API is the directory that contains the SLIM like Web Services. I want them to accessible only with the Web Application and want it to be secure and inaccessible by default.

What should be the common things like File Permissions, .htaccess that I need.